# Issue programming close button in aspx page using c# and html

Tags: c#, html

I'm trying to have a simple this.close(); feature in my aspx page however I seem to be having issues getting the C# to work in any capacity. I'm fairly new to c# so sorry if the issue is an obvious fix. Below is a screenshot of the small piece of code that I'm having issues with. Any help will be greatly appreciated and if more information is required don't hesitate to ask!

<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

Library manager
    
        body {
            background-color: #F1F1F1;
            padding: 20px;
        }

```
    header {
        height: 30%;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 20px;
    }

    section {
        height: 60%;
        width: 50%;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 20px;
        float: left;
    }

    footer {
        height: 10%;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 10px;
        clear: both;
    }

    table {
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: black;
        border-width: 3px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    td {
        border-color: red;
    }
</style>
```

```
<header>
    <img src="menager.PNG" height="100px" width="100px" style="float:left" />
    <input type="button" value="Add a book" />
    <input type="button" value="Add a copy" /><br />
    <input type="button" value="Withdraw a book" />
    <input type="button" value="Withdraw a copy" />
    <p><br /><br /><br />Menager</p>
</header>
<section>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search an user..." style="float:right"><br /><br />
    <br /><br /><br><input type="button" value="Reports" /><br /><br />
    <table style="width: 720px; height: 250px;">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="7" bgcolor="LemonChiffon">User</td>
        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor="lightgrey">
            <td>No.</td>
            <td>User_ID</td>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td>Future_Deadline</td>
            <td>Fine</td>
            <td>Payment_Status</td>
        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor="MediumOrchid">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>student@mail.com</td>
            <td>0251515</td>
            <td>11/12/2021</td>
            <td>5GBP</td>
            <td>PENDING</td>
        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor="MintCream">
            <td>2</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>student@mail.com</td>
            <td>0118715</td>
            <td>15/04/2021</td>
            <td>10GBP</td>
            <td>PENDING</td>
        </tr>

        <tr bgcolor="MediumOrchid">
            <td>3</td>
            <td>24</td>
            <td>student@mail.com</td>
            <td>01548615</td>
            <td>15/07/2021</td>
            <td>8GBP</td>
            <td>PENDING</td>
        </tr>

        <tr bgcolor="MintCream">
            <td>4</td>
            <td>25</td>
            <td>student@mail.com</td>
            <td>02569814</td>
            <td>14/08/2021</td>
            <td>4GBP</td>
            <td>PENDING</td>
        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor="MediumOrchid">
            <td>5</td>
            <td>26</td>
            <td>student@mail.com</td>
            <td>01456989</td>
            <td>16/09/2021</td>
            <td>17GBP</td>
            <td>PENDING</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </section>

    <footer>
        <input id="BtnClose" type="button" value="Close" style="float:right"/>
                 <%  private void BtnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

        this.Close();

    } %>
        <a href="Login.aspx"><input type="button" value="Log out" style="float:right" /></a>
    </footer>
```

[CloseButtonError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsAUR.png) [Webform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkLN4.png)

Comment: if possible post code snippet

Comment: Hey, appreciate the response, just to clarify so I give the right thing would you like to see a certain piece of code from the aspx page?

Comment: what you want to close on click of close button

Comment: I'm fairly new to coding so a lot of the terminology is still becoming familiar with me. I added another screenshot of what I'm closing with the button (It's a basic webform that should just close on click). I know you asked for a snippet but I'm not really sure I understand how to use a snippet

Comment: instead of img you copy and paste code

Comment: btnclose.Attributes.Add("onclick", "self.close()")

Comment: Added code into the original question! Sorry if its to long I wanted to make sure I got all relevant info.

Comment: This is a Javscript question, not c#. And that has limitations; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close